# media query not showing up

Tags: css, media-queries

I have a drop-down menu for mobile units that's working fine, I have also set up a media query for tablets where the code is slightly different. Its this part of the code that not showing up at all when on tablet screen widths. 
The default for the menu drop-down is set at margin-top: 52px; on line 524 in style-sheet. 
For the tablet I have set up the following code:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 481px) {
  .flexnav-show {
    margin-top: 0px; }
}
```

on line 630 in style-sheet. This part of the code is never implemented at all. 
This is the [website](http://gladahundar01.businesscatalyst.com/index.html) I am trying to make it work on.

Thanks,
Sohail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `min-device-width`

```
  @media all and (min-device-width: 481px) {
  .flexnav-show {
   margin-top: 0px; }
  }
```

Comment: That alone didn't do it, but then I added the !important directive, and that did it, thanks :)